# Can not create node group inputs and outputs using python

Tags: python, error, shader-nodes

I have written a code to create a `NodeGroup` using python inside Blender. `NodeGroup` and `GroupInput` and `GroupOutput` nodes inside `NodeGroup` are also created successfully. The `GroupInput` node works fine for creating sockets while the other `GroupOutput` node throws an error.

[image]

```
import bpy

def back_facing_node_group(name):
    #Create NodeGroup
    back_facing = bpy.data.node_groups.new(name,'ShaderNodeTree')
    #Group input node and its sockets
    group_inp = back_facing.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    group_inp.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Color')
    #Group output node and its sockets
    group_out = back_facing.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    group_out.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Color')
    #Group Nodes
    geo_node = back_facing.nodes.new('ShaderNodeNewGeometry')
    mix_node = back_facing.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixRGB')
    #Group Links
    back_facing.links.new(group_inp.outputs['Color'],mix_node.inputs[1])
    back_facing.links.new(geo_node.outputs[6], mix_node.inputs[0])
    back_facing.links.new(mix_node.outputs[0], group_out.inputs['Color'])
    return back_facing

group = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')
group.location = -300,200
group.node_tree = back_facing_node_group('Node_group')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the expected output then use the following script, you have to replace `group_inp.outputs.new` with `back_facing.outputs.new`

[image]

```
import bpy

def back_facing_node_group(name):
    #Create NodeGroup
    back_facing = bpy.data.node_groups.new(name,'ShaderNodeTree')
    #Group input node and its sockets
    group_inp = back_facing.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    back_facing.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Color')
    
    #Group output node and its sockets
    group_out = back_facing.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    back_facing.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Color')

    #Group Nodes
    geo_node = back_facing.nodes.new('ShaderNodeNewGeometry')
    mix_node = back_facing.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixRGB')
    
    #Group Links
    back_facing.links.new(group_inp.outputs['Color'],mix_node.inputs[1])
    back_facing.links.new(geo_node.outputs[6], mix_node.inputs[0])
    back_facing.links.new(mix_node.outputs[0], group_out.inputs['Color'])
    return back_facing

group = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')
group.location = -300,200
group.node_tree = back_facing_node_group('Node_group')
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

In **Blender 4.0** the "inputs" and "outputs" were removed from "bpy.types.NodeTree" (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/change_log.html#bpy-types-nodetree)

Thus adding and changing Node Group Inputs/Outputs is different now.
Here is an Example for adding a **Shader Node**

```
    #Add the Node Group
    someGroup = bpy.data.node_groups.new('someGroup', 'ShaderNodeTree')

    #Add the Input Sockets and change their Default Values
    someGroup.interface.new_socket(name="Some Color Input",description="some_color_input",in_out ="INPUT", socket_type="NodeSocketColor")
    someGroup.interface.items_tree[0].default_value = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
    someGroup.interface.new_socket(name="Some Float Input",description="some_float_input",in_out ="INPUT", socket_type="NodeSocketFloat")
    someGroup.interface.items_tree[1].default_value = 1.0

    #Add the Output Sockets and change their Default Value
    someGroup.interface.new_socket(name="Some Shader Output",description="some_shader_output",in_out ="OUTPUT", socket_type="NodeSocketShader")

    #Add Group Input/Output Nodes and position them
    group_input : bpy.types.ShaderNodeGroup = IndirectLightingGroup.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    group_input.location = (-340,80)
    group_output : bpy.types.ShaderNodeGroup = IndirectLightingGroup.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    group_output.location = (180,300)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy

def back_facing_node_group(name):
    #Create NodeGroup
    back_facing = bpy.data.node_groups.new(name,'ShaderNodeTree')
    #Group input node and its sockets
    group_inp = back_facing.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    group_inp.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Color')
    #Group output node and its sockets
    group_out = back_facing.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    #Group Nodes
    geo_node = back_facing.nodes.new('ShaderNodeNewGeometry')
    mix_node = back_facing.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixRGB')
    #Group Links
    back_facing.links.new(geo_node.outputs['Backfacing'], mix_node.inputs['Fac'])
    back_facing.links.new(group_inp.outputs['Color'], mix_node.inputs['Color1'])
    back_facing.links.new(mix_node.outputs['Color'], group_out.inputs[''])
    return back_facing

group = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')
group.location = -300,200
group.node_tree = back_facing_node_group('Node_group')
```